# Call function on link click, even if the link is newly added

Tags: javascript, jquery, onclick

Normally, if I wanted to call a function if a link is clicked, I would do this:

```
$('a').click(function() {
    //stuff
});
```

However, I need to call this function even if the element has been newly added. For example,

```
$('a').click(function() {
    //stuff
});
$(document.body).append($('<a href="http://example.com">This is an example</a>'))
//now when I click that example link, the function isn't called!
```

How can I make a function that applies to all links? I do not have control of the code that adds the new links, so I can't just set its `onclick` when it's added.

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4VMe4/1/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to delegate your click event using `.on()` like:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function(){...});
```

Per the doc for [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/):

> Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they
>   must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().
>   To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event
>   binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the
>   HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page,
>   select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is
>   placed into the page.

Note that using `$(document)` is considered a worst case example and you want to use an element closer in the DOM whenever possible.

> Attaching many delegated event handlers near the top of the document
>   tree can degrade performance. Each time the event occurs, jQuery must
>   compare all selectors of all attached events of that type to every
>   element in the path from the event target up to the top of the
>   document. For best performance, attach delegated events at a document
>   location as close as possible to the target elements. Avoid excessive
>   use of document or document.body for delegated events on large
>   documents.

Answer (score 4):

Use event delegation for registering events for dynamically added elements using [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/)

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', function() {
    //stuff
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/89bYe/)